# What is the best way to monitor resources and health check in Amazon web services

Tags: amazon-web-services

Could anyone tell me what are the best practices to perform a health check on AWS services and monitor the resources.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We'd love to assist you, but your question is not providing much detail. Please Edit your question and provide more information, such as: What exactly are you wishing to accomplish (with examples), what have you tried (sample code encouraged!) and what has been the result?

Answer (score 1):

depends on what service really.
ec2? then find a provider of your choice and install agent.

Not that I'm promoting any, but Datadog, Dynatrace, New Relic, Appdynamics all does infrastructure monitoring as well as APM.

For any other service? Some service offer Cloudwatch logs, you might have to parse these, or create SNS/SES so that you get alerted.